# Deleting MySQL Connections

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, connection, mysql-5.7

Topic:  MySQL Connections

Specific Question:  In a 2-3 week process of learning MySQL and attempting to get a Python stock info scrapping program to feed data into a MySQL schema (database, table) I’ve ended up creating a number of connections. (MySQL57, MySQL57_1,MySQL57Nov13)  Even though I believe I’ve deleted the connections through Workbench, they still show up as Window services.  How do I completely get rid of these beasts, both in MySQL and as Windows services?

System: Windows 8 64bit on a Xeon Ivy Bridge processor, large SSD’s, large HD’s, mucho RAM, dual X-fired video cards, ASUS Sabertooth MB (self-built a yr ago)

Software: MySQL 5.7, complete installation except for module for Visual Basic and Python3 (running 2.7).  Attempting to use the above hardware as both a server & client.

Even though I did my first Fortran programming in 1964, and spent my career on Unix machines, please regard me as a newbie when it come to the jargon associated with databases and client/server communications.

Why am I asking this question?  My “down the road question” will be about getting data from Python into the MySQL table, but “first things first” --- I would like to get a nice clean installation & am concerned with these connections showing up as windows services.

By the way, I’ve thoroughly scoured this site and many others but have not found any answers that fit my requirements; they’re either for a non-Windows environment, too full of jargon for me to understand, or too simplistic to be useful. Hope that didn't come across wrong :-)

TIA, Doug

Comment: Connections in Workbench is still configuration how Workbench connect to DB. So it is not DB it self.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-manage-db-connections.html

Comment: "Windows Services" = Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services?  If so, those aren't "connections," they are different installations of MySQL Server.  Please clarify what you see, and where.

Comment: Michael  Thanks for the response.  Yes, the "connections" that I can't get rid of could very well be different installations of MySQL.  They show up (as you spelled out) in Control Panel->AdTools->Services.  I've looked in the Program files, registry, etc to find the extra instances ... so far no luck.  The names definitely correspond to names I gave to the "connection" that shows up in the upper left corner (overall black screen) when you first open MySQL.

Comment: Michael   Following up on your helpful comments I've searched removing unwanted installations (installed as Window services).  This link  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-start-service.html
sort of addresses the situation, however wouldn't   
C:\> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld" --remove  remove all the installations.  I'd like to leave the basic one. Thanks Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the uninstallation command already, so let me show you how to make sure not to remove the wrong service.

Open the services management (e.g. via Start menu -> Computer -> right click -> Manage -> Services and Applications -> Services). Scroll to the MySQL server services and double click one that you want to uninstall. A dialog opens with various information about the service including a line "Path to executable:". The followoing line contains the full path to the server this service is for. You should only have one service for each of the servers. If that is not the case then you probably have to go through the registry and search for the service name and remove that key manually, until only one is left. Otherwise just use the path to run your uninstallation if that is for a server/service you don't want anymore.

Answer (score 0):

My problem (as described in my original question) has been solved thanks to the comments that Michael made.

In a command prompt with admin privileges

***net stop MySQL57Nov13*** (service name)
 to stop the service (all 3 of my services)

```
Note: I had cd'd to  D:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin  to run the net stop
```

commands.  I have a hunch that the commands would have worked independent of the directory chosen 
to run them from....didn't experiment further though.  Likely depends on the PATH env var.

Then go to C:>

***sc delete MySQL57Nov13***

```
for all 3 services I wanted to delete
```

As a reference I used   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-troubleshooting.html

The above was written prior to Mike's answer.

Later update:  This is a *%@&!! nightmare!   Obviously I deleted the key windows service (was one of MySQL57, MySQL57_1, or MySQL57Nov13).  This effectively cratered the entire project ... couldn't create a new, fresh connection or anything else.   So I uninstalled everything (to the best of my knowledge) using the internal MySQL Uninstall routine as opposed to Windows Program Management uninstall.   Fortunately I've got no data which I have to save.

I'll start a new question later today.... I'm going to uninstall the mess again, and start from scratch (the new question will be concerning the MySQL import hanging when I tried to import a .sql file tied to a tutorial I've been watching)

Let's consider my Question solved with many thanks to Michael and Mike